# Can connect client to server socket linux

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I have code the client socket like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string>
#include<unistd.h> //close
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    //create a socket
    int network_socket;
    network_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    int port;
    string IPaddress;

    cout << "Input port(ex 9999):";
    cin >> port;
    cin.ignore(1, '\n');

    cout << "Input IP address(ex 127.0.0.1):" << endl;
    getline(cin, IPaddress, '\n');
    //specify an address for the socket
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IPaddress);
    server_address.sin_port = htons(port);
}
```

I try to connect my server by input Port and ip address but when I convert to linux. It perform **inet_addr’ was not declared in this scope;** . How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you include arpa/inet.h (if on Linux) or Winsock2.h (if on Windows)?

Comment: *"... code ... like this"* - the problem comes from not including the relevant header files. Unfortunately you only show a snipped of your code which does not include any header files at all. So it is not clear what you include and what is missing. See [the man page for inet_addr](https://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_addr) what is needed.

Comment: @EagleOne yeah I included that library. Sorry I forgot mention library

Comment: @EagleOne Thank you I  have included arpa/inet.h. It worked